# What is the minimum cache length I can specify without request rejection in Remote Config?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-remote-config

I have been trying to figure out whether I can utilize Remote Config to set maintenance mode in a React Native project without caching issues.

> To bypass caching fully, you can pass a value of 0. Be warned Firebase may start to reject your requests if values are requested too frequently.

According to the [Remote Config documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/remote-config/usage#caching) like above, it seems like I am able to specify my own cache length as 0 but it can possibly cause request rejections.

Then, I wonder if it is okay to set a value other than 0 such as 30000 to the `minimumFetchIntervalMillis` property to avoid rejections, or is there any certain minimum cache length to do so?

Thank you in advance.

Soo

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for information on Firebase's rate limiting structure.

You can find their explanation here (at time of writing): https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas

You'll fall within one of several pricing categories - you can use this to predict your costs based on your usage.  Firebase is built to scale, so they should be able to handle a good amount of traffic.